# Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

I want to publish my project but:

Error1

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://xxxxx:xxxx/msdeploy.axd?site=VoIP'.)
>
> Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://xxxxx:xxxx/msdeploy.axd?site=VoIP'.
> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: It seems that just restarting Visual Studio often fixes this.

Comment: I just had this in the context of publishing to Windows Azure. A restart of VS2012 Premium fixed it as Gert suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, restarting VS2012 worked for me as well.

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio and trying again.

Comment: Doing a restart of VS2012 worked for me, I did have it open for quite a while.

Comment: This fixes it for me, but I have to restart VS every 3-4 times I push

Comment: I've also found restarting the Web Deployment Agent Service on the server is sometimes required

Comment: I guess someone could report this BUG to Microsoft, if it hasn't been done before

Comment: The answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841370/cant-get-my-ec2-windows-server-2008-web-stack-instance-to-receive-publishings
helped me greatly in a similar-sounding case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and was fixed, but only if you have the Azure SDK:

[Publish Wizard Errors in VS2010 and 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918234/publish-wizard-errors-in-vs2010-and-2012/12376504#12376504)

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773902/every-now-and-then-i-cant-publish-to-azure-get-com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used

Answer (score 0):

1) Open port **8172** on server if not

2) Make sure you have web deployment tools installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that internet proxy was enabled for the account, which was making the MSDeploy request to go to internet instead of local network.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I attempted to restart the Web Management service it would fail... Manually restarting using:

```
Net start wmsvc
```

gave me the response:

```
A service specific error occurred: 2147483656.
```

That led me to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/web-management-service-issue-2147483656/ba-p/1942557).

Effectively I had deleted the cert used by Management Services when updating my SSL certificates (forehead slap), and it didn't know which cert to use.

I went into IIS, clicked on the Server, double clicked the Management Service screen.
[image]

I then selected my new SSL Certificate, clicked apply, then restart and I was back in business.
[image]